# How to hide/lock linked PostgreSQL tables when MS Access is used as a front end and PostgreSQL as backend?

Tags: database, postgresql, ms-access, frontend, backend

I have MS Access as a front end and PostgreSQL as back end for my database. So I set up the database in PostgreSQL and linked the tables to MS Access using the ODBC drivers. Everything works great, I can update the tables in MS Access and the record will appear in Postgres database.

Since I can still see the linked tables in MS Access, I feel like it is possible for some users to go in and manually modify the tables without filling out proper forms. Is it possible to HIDE the tables or lock the tables so that Access users cannot modify the raw data at all? If not, what can I do to secure the integrity of the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at *Postgres* [privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-priv.html) as a way to lock the tables down.

In short, you could have your backend run as one user that has full access permissions on the tables in question, and when the users login to the app, they would be connected to *Postgres* using a user whose privileges are considerably more locked down (say, read only if you just want to be able to do `SELECT`s to surface data).

For example, you could run the following SQL against your *Postgres* server:

```
REVOKE ALL ON accounts FROM joe;
GRANT SELECT ON accounts TO joe;
```

Which would first remove all privileges from the user **joe** for the table **accounts**, and then allow only `SELECT` priveleges for that table.

You could do something similar for all the *tables* you wish to lock down. You'll also need to do the same for the *sequences* used by those tables.

You may wish to create a special **readonly** user which has only read access across the board, and use those credentials to surface the *Postgres* data for the users to access.

When you need to alter data, your backend could specifically use a *power* user of sorts which has much greater access.

Here's a link which details creating a *readonly* *Postgres* user (for purposes of backups in this case, but the general concept and the *SQL* commands should apply (just ignore the stuff about *pg_dump*).

If you aren't concerned about users' ability to modify the data in those tables via the up other than in the ways that are authorized, but are only concerned about them using, say, *psql* to go in and update them, then you probably don't need a *readonly* user, but can simply lock the tables down and have the backend use that user with sufficient access.